# google app engine python configuration

Tags: python, google-app-engine

when I run my app using "Google App Engine Launcher" it gives me a warning sign.

in the log console I found it using Python 3.3, how can I configure it to use python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Launcher go to Edit -> Preferences and set Python Path to match your python 27 path.